# Multiple nested spread operators inside of an array (javascript es2015)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm working with a reducer using the React / Redux architecture. It's not specifically relevant to my question, as this is more of an ES2015 question. I have the following code:

```
return objectAssign({}, state, {
        sendingRequest: false,
        currentModel: {
            ...state.currentModel,
            components: [
                ...state.currentModel.components,
                0: {
                    ...state.currentModel.components[0], // can't do this, why?
                    selectedComponentGroup: {
                        ...state.currentModel.components[0].selectedComponentGroup,
                        availableComponents: action.payload.data
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    });
```

However, ESLint is throwing an error:

```
✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/  Parsing error: Unexpected token  
C:\...\ProjectModelsReducer.js:122:25
...state.currentModel.components[action.componentIndex],
```

It's complaining specifically about the spread operator for this line:

```
...state.currentModel.components[action.componentIndex]
```

I can't figure out why this doesn't work and I was wondering if someone could shed some light into why the spread operator can't be used here.

Comment: Sounds like you've got experimental `stage-x` stuff enabled for Babel, but don't have ESLint configured to parse using Babel. Spreading objects is not standard ECMAScript.

Comment: You cannot have `0: ` inside an array literal.

Comment: Oh good call, missed that the spread there was an array and not an object, so this is a syntax error in general, not just ESLint.

Comment: @Bergi Why is that? How would I change the contents of the object that's at array index 0?

Comment: Like this? `[state.currentModel.components[0]]:`

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Comment: Okay, technically you're correct, but it is the umbrella term that is used throughout the industry. [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/spread-operator-decrement-dot-dot-dot-javascript) and the [Official Redux Docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html) both use the term "spread operator".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
components: [
    ...state.currentModel.components,
    0: {
        // ...
    }
]
```

is not valid, just like `[0: {}]` is not valid as an array declaration. If you want to create a new array with a specific item changed, you'd have to use spread along with normal array syntax, or clone the array and mutate the index later, e.g.

```
components: [
    {
        // ...
    },
    ...state.currentModel.components.slice(1),
]
```

to create a new array with the first item replaced, or do

```
components: Object.assign([...state.currentModel.components], {
    0: {
        // ...
    }
}),
```

to clone the array then change the item at the `0` index.

Comment: Yeah, that was where I went wrong. The declarative nature of the Redux reducers screwed me up. Long day of looking at code. Needed some extra eyes :). Your second example is essentially what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a place where I can learn this? (spread operator object beyond the basics, with examples) Every tutorial I see shows the same exact thing

Answer (score 0):

I see my mistake now. I was treating the array like an object and using the index as a key in the array, but the array doesn't use keys when they are being defined. I have to do something like this:

```
components: [
    ...state.currentModel.components,
    {
        0: {
            ...state.currentModel.components[0],
            selectedComponentGroup: {
                ...state.currentModel.components[0].selectedComponentGroup,
                availableComponents: action.payload.data
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Ultimately I ended up using the [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) to make the update more clean.

```
components: update(state.currentModel.components, {
    0: {
        $merge: {
            selectedComponentGroup: {
                ...state.currentModel.components[0].selectedComponentGroup,
                availableComponents: action.payload.data
            }
        }
    }
})
```